# Possibilidade de pesquisar em uma ou mais colunas da mesma tabela SQL

Tags: php, mysql

Eu tenho uma tala onde vários produtos são exibidos. No lado esquerdo, existem várias opções para que a pessoa possa fazer filtros na lista de produtos.

Estou tentando criar um formulário se a variável tiver valor, ela será montada em partes.

Este é o meu código:

```
if (!empty($_GET) && (!empty($_GET['search']))) {
    $where = "WHERE"; 
}else{
    $url_atual = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['search']) && ($_GET['search'] != "")) {
    $serch = "titulo LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' ";
}else{
    $serch = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['cat']) && ($_GET['cat'] != "")) {
    $cat = "AND categoria = ".$_GET['cat']." ";
}else{
    $cat = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['cat_sub']) && ($_GET['cat_sub'] != "")) {
    $cat_sub = "AND subcategoria IN ('".$_GET['cat_sub']."')";
}else{
    $cat_sub = "";
}

if (isset($_GET['fpag']) && ($_GET['fpag'] != "all")) {
    $fpag = "AND fixoHora = '".$_GET['fpag']."' ";
}else{
    $fpag = "";
}


$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$where} {$serch} {$cat} {$cat_sub} {$fpag} LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}");
```

### Problema

Como eu estou usando `AND`, no início das variáveis, se alguma variável não for inicializada, como `search`, do erro, porque ele começaria assim:

```
SELECT * FROM projetos AND cat = 1
```

Existe uma maneira melhor de fazer essas pesquisas?

Obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

```
if (!empty($_GET) && (!empty($_GET['search']))) {
    $where = "WHERE"; 
$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$where} LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}");

}else if (isset($_GET['search']) && ($_GET['search'] != "")) {
    $serch = "titulo LIKE '%".$_GET['search']."%' ";
$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$serch}  LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}");

}else if (isset($_GET['cat']) && ($_GET['cat'] != "")) {
    $cat = "AND categoria = ".$_GET['cat']." ";
$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$cat}  LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}")

}else if (isset($_GET['cat_sub']) && ($_GET['cat_sub'] != "")) {
    $cat_sub = "AND subcategoria IN ('".$_GET['cat_sub']."')";
}else if (isset($_GET['fpag']) && ($_GET['fpag'] != "all")) {
    $fpag = "AND fixoHora = '".$_GET['fpag']."' ";
$projetos = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM projetos {$fpag} LIMIT {$inicio},{$itens_por_pagina}"); 

}
```

Comment: Não da, porque já na segunda condição daria erro. por não ter o WHERE,

Comment: como ta tua tabela no banco de dados?

Comment: Não entendi o sentido da pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

simples, antes das checagens quando você define o WHERE, coloca WHERE 1=1 ai TODAS as variaveis você usa o AND,
ou seja, se qualquer um valor não existir, ele vai usar WHERE 1=1 (sempre verdadeiro e executa o SQL), se vier alguma condição ela vai sempre ser iniciada com AND, ai a saida final fica WHERE 1=1 AND c1=v1

Comment: Eu fiz nesse sentido mesmo, deu certo.